# test for browser's ability to play a wav file in javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, embed

Is there a way to test for browser's ability to play a wav file in javascript

```
function playSound(myWAVfile)
    {   
        if (soundEmbed)
        {
           document.body.removeChild(soundEmbed);
        }
        soundEmbed = document.createElement("embed");
        soundEmbed.setAttribute("src", myWAVfile);
        soundEmbed.setAttribute("hidden", true);
        soundEmbed.setAttribute("autostart", true);
        document.body.appendChild(soundEmbed);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help you a lot: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/

Comment: looks promising, but I am looking for code to detect browser support for sound in javascript. Application is designed for mobile devices, so would prefer to avoid additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html5

```
<audio id="audio-tag-element" controls="" src=myWAVfile tabindex="0"></audio>
```

*Ie8 and less will not work*

Comment: specifically looking if there is a way to detect browser support for sound in javascript.